# Tools for calculating annotators agreement

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, nlp, computer-science

I am looking for a tool for calculating inter annotators agreement for two annotators in the case of [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification).

I was trying to use [ReCal online tool](http://dfreelon.org/utils/recalfront/), but it seems that ReCal doesn't support multi-label cllassification.

Are you aware of any tool for multi-label classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-statistics/ . However, it is not a 'ready-to-use tool', it is a library and it requires a bit of coding to fit your data into its data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in python using something like Krippendorff's alpha:

```
from nltk.metrics.agreement import AnnotationTask

task_data = [('coder1','Item0',frozenset(['l1','l2'])),
    ('coder2','Item0',frozenset(['l1'])),
    ('coder1','Item1',frozenset(['l1','l2'])),
    ('coder2','Item1',frozenset(['l1','l2'])),
    ('coder1','Item2',frozenset(['l1'])),
    ('coder2','Item2',frozenset(['l1']))]

task = AnnotationTask()

task.load_array(task_data)

print(task.alpha())
```